# Accessing Jenkins build version in code

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, build, spring-boot-actuator

Using the spring-boot-actuator, I can access my project's current build version when I enter the uri myApp:8080/.../env. Env is a spring actuator endpoint.

This uri, returns, among other data, my current build version --  info.build.version_component":"1.0.101".

I want to have access to the build version in my code for logging purposes. Is there a way I can access this data coming from the env endpoint and print it in my code?